# How to Fetch @OneToMany and @ManyToMany Entities

Tags: java, hibernate, fetch

my issue is very related to the following:
[Why am I getting a Hibernate LazyInitializationException in this Spring MVC web application when the data displays correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631695/why-am-i-getting-a-hibernate-lazyinitializationexception-in-this-spring-mvc-web-a)

I have the following properties on a particular entity:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE})
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", name = "ID_FORMAT_FILE")
private List<ColumnFormat> columnList;
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "FILEFORMAT_ORIGINATOR", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name =   "FILEFORMAT_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")
    , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ORIGINATOR_ID", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private List<Originator> originators;
```

As you might have noticed I have an Eager Fetch type on both relations, but it is giving the following:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags
    at org.hibernate.loader.BasicLoader.postInstantiate(BasicLoader.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.EntityLoader.<init>(EntityLoader.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.EntityLoader.<init>(EntityLoader.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.EntityLoader.<init>(EntityLoader.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.BatchingEntityLoader.createBatchingEntityLoader(BatchingEntityLoader.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createEntityLoader(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1914)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createEntityLoader(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1937)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createLoaders(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3205)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.postInstantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3191)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.postInstantiate(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:728)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:902)
    ... 33 more
```

I must access both lists `List<ColumnFormat> columnList` and `List<Originator> originators` on different beans, but if both are of **Fetch Type** *Eager* I get the above problem, and if one of them is *Lazy* I get the following:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.FileFormat.originators, no session or session was closed
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.readElementExistence(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag.contains(PersistentBag.java:262)
    at java.util.ArrayList.batchRemove(ArrayList.java:632)
    at java.util.ArrayList.removeAll(ArrayList.java:605)
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.bean.FileFormatEdit.init(FileFormatEdit.java:1040)
    ... 75 more
```

Is there a way to retrieve the lists on the different beans without having these problems?

Comment: could you post some codes which you use to retrieve the data?

Comment: An answer can be found here : [Hibernate cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4335514/251745)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haven't encountered this problem before, but just googling "cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags" returns [this link](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=959478) on the Hibernate forums.

One of the [blog posts](http://blog.eyallupu.com/2010/06/hibernate-exception-simultaneously.html) in that link may contain the solution you're looking for.

Comment: The links you gave certainly helped. Thanks, still working on the solution

Comment: I will accept your answer because it solves the actual question I posed, however given a new requirement I had to solve it on a different way.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted all `fetch=FetchType.EAGER` and it work correct. I´m usign Hibernate 3.5.6-Final, Spring 3.0.4 and Junit 4. I think fetch-EAGER is by default, because my object loads all children.

This is sessionFactory:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
    p:packagesToScan="org.pfc.modelo">

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="format_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This is class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="D_ACTIVIDAD")
public class Actividad implements Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="SQ_ACTIVIDAD",name="seqActividad")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="seqActividad")
private Integer idActividad;

@Column(name="FECHA",nullable=false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Calendar fecha;

@Column(name="TITULO",nullable=false)
private String titulo;

@Column(name="TEXTO",nullable=false)
private String texto;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="IDASOCIACION")
private Asociacion asociacion;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="actividad",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
private List<ComentarioActividad> comentarios;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="actividad",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
@OrderBy(value="fecha")
private List<Documento> documentos;

     //set and get methods 
     ...........
     ...........
     ...........

   }
```