# Help me test a one-to-many realtionship with NHibernate and NUnit

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nunit

I have a class, Task, and it has a property TaskLibrary which is dll it will load and run some code from. So, any task has one library, but any library can have many tasks. My problem is that my test for making sure the task's Library property is not null is failing (so it could just be my test). My classes are effectively this:

```
public class Task
{
  public virtual int TaskId {get;set;}
  public virtual string Locked {get;set;}
  public virtual int Status {get;set;}
  public virtual TaskLibrary Library {get;set;}
}

public class TaskLibrary
{
  public virtual int LibraryId {get;set}
  public virtual string Name {get;set;}
  public virtual string Description {get;set;}
  public virtual byte[] Dll {get;set}
  public virtual IEnumerable<Task> Tasks {get;set;}
}
```

My NHibernate mappings look like this:

```
  <class name="Task">
    <id name="Id" column="TaskId" type="Int32" unsaved-value="-1">
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Locked" column="Locked"/>
    <property name="Status" column="Status"/>
    <many-to-one name="Library" class="TaskLibrary" fetch="join"/>
  </class>
  <class name="TaskLibrary">
    <id name="Id" column="LibraryId">
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Name"/>
    <property name="Description"/>
    <property name="Dll"/>
    <set name="Tasks" lazy="true">
      <key column="LibraryId"/>
      <one-to-many class="Task"/>
    </set>
  </class>
```

My test class looks like this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TaskRepositoryFixture
{
    private ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
    private Configuration _configuration;

    private readonly Task[] _tasks = new[]
        {
            new Task {Id = 1, Status = 1, Locked = 0, Library = new TaskLibrary { Id =1, Description = "Test Library", Name = "Tast.dll", Type = "RunnableTask", Dll = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test binary data")}},
            new Task {Id = 2, Status = 1, Locked = 0, Library = new TaskLibrary { Id =1, Description = "Test Library", Name = "Tast.dll", Type = "RunnableTask", Dll = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test binary data")}},
            new Task {Id = 3, Status = 1, Locked = 0, Library = new TaskLibrary { Id =2, Description = "Test Library 2", Name = "Tast2.dll", Type = "RunnableTask", Dll = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test binary data")}},
            new Task {Id = 4, Status = 1, Locked = 0, Library = new TaskLibrary { Id =2, Description = "Test Library 2", Name = "Tast2.dll", Type = "RunnableTask", Dll = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test binary data")}},
            new Task {Id = 5, Status = 1, Locked = 0, Library = new TaskLibrary { Id =3, Description = "Test Library 3", Name = "Tast3.dll", Type = "RunnableTask", Dll = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test binary data")}},
        };

    private readonly TaskLibrary[] _libraries = new[]
        {
            new TaskLibrary { Id =1, Description = "Test Library", Name = "Tast.dll", Type = "RunnableTask", BinaryDll = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test binary data")},
            new TaskLibrary { Id =2, Description = "Test Library 2", Name = "Tast2.dll", Type = "RunnableTask", BinaryDll = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test binary data")},
            new TaskLibrary { Id =3, Description = "Test Library 3", Name = "Tast3.dll", Type = "RunnableTask", BinaryDll = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test binary data")}
        };

    private void CreateInitialData()
    {
        using (ISession session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            foreach (var lib in _libraries)
                session.Save(lib);

            foreach (var task in _tasks)
                session.Save(task);

            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }


    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void TestFixtureSetUp()
    {
        _configuration = new Configuration();
        _configuration.Configure();
        _configuration.AddAssembly("DistPollAutoTasksShared");
        _sessionFactory = _configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    [SetUp]
    public void SetupContext()
    {
        new SchemaExport(_configuration).Execute(false, true, false, false);
        CreateInitialData();
    }

    [Test]
    public void CanGetLibraryFromTask()
    {
        ITaskRepository repository = new TaskRepository();
        var fromDb = repository.GetById(_tasks[0].Id);
        Assert.IsNotNull(fromDb.Library);
        Assert.IsNotNull(fromDb.Library.Dll);
    }
  }
```

And, the Tasks table in the MSSQL2000 database is this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tasks](
    [TaskId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TaskLibrary] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Status] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Locked] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

If you're still with me...

From my Task class, I just want an instance of the TaskLibrary class for the Library property. Also, if I'm working with the libraries themselves, I want to be able to lazily retrieve an IEnumerable of all tasks using that library. However, when I run the test, I get this error:

```
TestCase 'DistPollAutoTasksShared.Tests.TaskRepositoryFixture.CanGetLibraryFromTask'
failed: NHibernate.LazyInitializationException : Could not initialize proxy - no Session.
    at NHibernate.Proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.Initialize()
    at NHibernate.Proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.GetImplementation()
    at NHibernate.Proxy.Poco.Castle.CastleLazyInitializer.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
    at TaskLibraryProxy2bd44073e90f47298039abfbfda11492.get_Dll()
```

This is the first time I've used NHibernate, so I'm still learning. I really want to get a good foundation of the basics, so I'm stuck here until then. Any help, suggestions, reading material (I've read all of [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009110/learning-nhibernate) suggestions and some others) would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

After changing fetch="join", I'm getting the functionality I want from the Task class. However, I've added another test for the Tasks property of the TaskLibrary class:

```
    [Test]
    public void CanGetTasksByLibrary()
    {
        ITaskLibraryRepository repository = new TaskLibraryRepository();
        var fromDb = repository.GetById(_libraries[0].Id).Tasks;

        Assert.IsNotNull(fromDb);
        Assert.True(fromDb.Count() == 2, "Cannot get IEnumerable<Task> from TaskLibrary");
    }
```

But, an assertion fails with this error (I've updated the code above to reflect any changes I've made):

```
TestCase 'DistPollAutoTasksShared.Tests.TaskLibraryRepositoryFixture.CanGetTasksByLibrary'
failed: 
  Cannot get IEnumerable<Tasks> from TaskLibrary
  Expected: True
  But was:  False
```

Comment: This is because you can only lazy load while the session is open. You would not want to eagerly load the TaskLibrary.Tasks as this could end up with a shit ton of select statements being issued recursively.

Comment: @dotjoe, right. That's why I've set lazy="true", but it's still throwing the exception. So, I must not understand how the lazy loading works.

Comment: Basically lazy loading works by extending your poco (with virtual properties) and when you access one of the properties it tries to use the session it was loaded with. If the session was closed you get the error. So in your case, the session is open and closed before you attempt to access the Tasks.

Comment: @dotjoe I see, and that is the case. My repository opens and closes a session for each method (which is the way the tutorial I followed had it). What you are saying is that for lazy loading, I should only use one session for the duration of the Repository's lifetime, instead of the methods'?

Comment: @dotjoe, but the processing in the repo is done:
TaskLibrary tl = taskLibraryRepo.GetById(1); //done with repo
Now, I have an instance of TaskLibrary, tl, of which I want to lazily load the Tasks. If taskLibraryRepo falls out of scope, how do you load the Tasks of tl?

Comment: You could simply have a method like `GetTasksByLibrary(int library_id)` and remove the Tasks property. Actually, have you tried setting the Tasks to non-lazy? I'm not sure if that will have to re-query the TaskLibrary since that object is already loaded. I was thinking it was a many-to-many in the first comment.

Comment: @dotjoe, or have the Tasks property's get accessor call a private GetAllTasks() method? I suppose that would still be lazy.

Comment: Yes, that could work. It'd be like your own custom lazy loading. Just make sure you only load it once. You wouldn't want to load it every time that property is accessed.

Comment: Disregard that previous comment I deleted...it is common to leave the session open for a unit of work. If it is a web site, you would leave session open while processing a single request. Here is an example on how one might do that...http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#quickstart-playingwithcats

Comment: I think I've got the lazy loading bit down, but still, when I try and get any of the tasks, from the TaskLibrary, there are none (as shown in the last test).

Comment: hmm, what is the TaskLibrary key in the Task table? you can specify that in the many-to-one with the column attribute. It looks like you expect it to be `LibraryID` but it is defined as `TaskLibrary`. The set's key column should equal the Library key in the task table.

Comment: @dotjoe, I think the problem is my limited understanding of NHibernate and my association of it to the code and to my database schema. Really there is no relationship between the TaskLibrary and Tasks, in that TaskLibraries do not have Tasks, but Tasks have TaskLibraries. I think I will have to implement my own property as we discussed earlier for this lookup ability. I don't think it can really be mapped in the NHibernate mapping files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<many-to-one name="Library" class="TaskLibrary" fetch="join" />
```

This would join the Library on every select.

```
<many-to-one name="Library" class="TaskLibrary" lazy="false" />
```

This will eagerly execute separate select for the Library.

Otherwise, it will lazy load the Library if you only set fetch="select" (which is the default).

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/09/nhibernate-mapping-ltmany-to-onegt.aspx

http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-lazy

Comment: So what's the difference between the lazy and fetch attributes?

Comment: yes, you could also simply set lazy="false" on the many-to-one and it will issue the separate select statement right away. When you set  fetch="join" I think lazy attribute has no meaning...I'm not 100% on that though.

Answer (score 0):

did you try setting Lazy="false" in your mapping?
http://code-redefined.blogspot.com/2007/07/hibernate-lazy-fetch-problems-could-not.html

Comment: Also check the unit of work you're dealing with... if each access is wrapped in it's own transaction, you could be getting the No Session error. See this for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345705/hibernate-lazyinitializationexception-could-not-initialize-proxy

Comment: I did just now, but I get the same exception. Although, I  do want lazy loading of Tasks from the TaskLibrary class.

Answer (score 0):

Dont change the mapping for the test  , your requirements should drive how objects are mapped .
Your repository method is closing the session after fetching fromDB. You need to keep the session open for the whole test method.
  To figure out how to do that you need to tell us how you are managing your session . Are those tied to a transaction / threadlocal ?

Comment: That's not how I understand it. The test should be created first to drive your code creation (i.e. the first run of your test should fail). I understand your point, but I'm still new to NHibernate so I can't just map it the way I've designed right off.

Comment: ok sure . So you test should reflect how sessions are being managed in real case. Is it session per operation like in you test?. If that is the case sure go ahead make it non lazy ( i personally very rarely make anything not lazy )

Comment: I think my problem was the tutorial I followed. Now that I have a little better understanding of NHibernate, I'll have to modify my repositories.