# Container-managed persistence contexts: transaction-scoped vs. extended - how to decide?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb, eclipselink

There's a lot of technical "blurp" out on the Internet, books and elsewhere where you can read a lot about how to setup **container-managed persistence contexts** etc., but none of the sources I've found deal with the *much more difficult question*:

How do you decide on which type of container-managed persistence context to use? How do you decide between *container-managed* **transaction-scoped** and *container-managed* **extended** *persistence contexts* conceptually?

How do you approach this? What are the crucial points here? Is there a more-or-less generally accepted policy that can be applied? Maybe we/you can develop one here...

I'm *really* struggling to find a useful answer to this. Help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547817/what-is-the-difference-between-transaction-scoped-persistence-context-and-extend) and [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/extended_persistence_context_in_stateful), you would use the Extended Persistence Context only if you deal with stateful EJBs.

Comment: Well, because I didn't post the question as I should have, this only applies to directly injecting an entity manager into some bean via `@PersistenceContext`.