# lazy exception using spring framework 3, hibernate and websphere transaction manager

Tags: spring, hibernate, websphere, transactionmanager

i am just upgrading my spring framework to spring 3.1.1 and i am using websphere transaction manager. when i was trying to access a model which is declared as lazy i got the following error:

> [1/15/13 14:30:46:148 WIT] 00000021 LazyInitializ E
>   org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException  could not initialize
>   proxy - no Session
>                                    org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy
>   - no Session  at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:57)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:111)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBLazyInitializer.invoke(CGLIBLazyInitializer.java:150)
>     at
>   com.aprisma.product.gcm.common.model.spi.gie.Menu$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$ebdf1c09.getName()
>     at
>   com.aprisma.product.gcm.service.integration.impl.SecurityServiceImpl.getMenuTree(SecurityServiceImpl.java:312)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)     at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.doInTransaction(TransactionInterceptor.java:132)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager$UOWActionAdapter.run(WebSphereUowTransactionManager.java:337)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.uow.UOWManagerImpl.runUnderNewUOW(UOWManagerImpl.java:1067)
>     at com.ibm.ws.uow.UOWManagerImpl.runUnderUOW(UOWManagerImpl.java:628)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager.execute(WebSphereUowTransactionManager.java:281)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
>     at $Proxy1104.getMenuTree(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.aprisma.product.gcm.service.impl.LoginServiceImpl.getMenuTree(LoginServiceImpl.java:279)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)     at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.doInTransaction(TransactionInterceptor.java:132)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager$UOWActionAdapter.run(WebSphereUowTransactionManager.java:337)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.uow.UOWManagerImpl.runUnderNewUOW(UOWManagerImpl.java:1067)
>     at com.ibm.ws.uow.UOWManagerImpl.runUnderUOW(UOWManagerImpl.java:628)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager.execute(WebSphereUowTransactionManager.java:281)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
>     at $Proxy1335.getMenuTree(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)     at
>   com.aprisma.component.esm.utils.CallUtils.springCall1(CallUtils.java:452)
>     at
>   com.aprisma.component.esm.utils.CallUtils.springCall2(CallUtils.java:465)
>     at
>   com.aprisma.component.esm.utils.CallUtils.springCall(CallUtils.java:413)
>     at com.aprisma.component.esm.utils.CallUtils.call(CallUtils.java:777)
>     at
>   com.aprisma.component.esm.delegate.BusinessObjectFactory.callBusinessObject(BusinessObjectFactory.java:275)
>     at
>   com.aprisma.component.web2.service.CallBOService.callService(CallBOService.java:9)
>     at
>   com.aprisma.product.gcm.retail.web.mvc.AbstractController.callService(AbstractController.java:45)
>     at
>   com.aprisma.product.gcm.retail.web.mvc.customer.LoginController.prepareMenuList(LoginController.java:376)
>     at
>   com.aprisma.product.gcm.retail.web.mvc.customer.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:215)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)     at
>   org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
>     at
>   com.aprisma.component.web2.servlet.CustomDispatcherServlet.doDispatch(CustomDispatcherServlet.java:17)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)  at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
>     at
>   com.aprisma.component.web.filters.UserContextFilter.doFilterInternal(UserContextFilter.java)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
>     at
>   com.aprisma.component.web.filters.InputSanitationFilter.doFilter(InputSanitationFilter.java)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:934)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:864)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:557)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:607)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:984)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1069)
>     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)

The problem only occured when i am using websphere transaction manager, if i am using weblogic transaction manager it works fine. I have tried to search for the same problem but it seems like no one had the same problem with me. So, i would like to ask if anyone ever faced the same problem? is there any solution for this?

thank you,
robin

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345705/hibernate-lazyinitializationexception-could-not-initialize-proxy should answer your question

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply, but my problem actually occured when i am using spring 3.1.1 and websphere transaction manager, prevously, i am using spring 2.5.6 and websphere transaction manager and it works just fine and if i am using spring 3.1.1 with weblogic transaction manager, it also works fine. There are no changes to my source code. thank you