# Despite @Transactional, failed to lazily initialize a collection of role

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

Inside the following controller

```
   @Transactional
   @PostMapping(PATH_VARIABLE)
   public void assignStuff(
         @PathVariable final long someNo,
         @PathVariable final long someId)
         throws AccessDeniedException, ValidationException, ResourceNotFoundException
   {
      final Set<SomeEntity> createdEntities = someService.assignSomething(
            resolveData(someNo, someId)
      );

      if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(createdEntties))
      {
         anotherService.publishPackageDataChangeEvent(someNo);
      }
   }
```

the following exception is thrown

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: someEntity, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:582)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:201)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:561)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.iterator(PersistentSet.java:163)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.estimateSize(Spliterators.java:1821)
    at java.util.Spliterator.getExactSizeIfKnown(Spliterator.java:408)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at aThirdService.thingsChanged(SomeCalculator.java:61)
```

From [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643098/failed-to-lazily-initialize-a-collection-of-role-could-not-initialize-proxy) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345705/hibernate-lazyinitializationexception-could-not-initialize-proxy), it seems like this should be fixed with @Transactional, right? So why does it still occur?

Comment: Did you check the import of Transactional ? Are you calling the Method from a Rest Controller or a Scheduler ? Are you calling the public Method from outside the class or inside the class?

Comment: @GJohannes: it's a spring controller, so it's called from the outside. The import is `import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;`

Comment: Did you add `@EnableTransactionManagement`?

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko : yes, `@Transactional` works in general.

Comment: What does `resolveData` do? And what does `assignSomething` do?

Comment: @JensSchauder: `resolveData` is some simple computation. `assignSomething` goes through the very deep entity structure to fetch values and also save them to the database.